# replace all "foo" between two HTML tags using REGEX (PHP code)

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex code , to replace all "foo" strings to "bar" , between the html tags pre>< /pre>

here is an example :

```
< html>
< p> blah blah blah foo try foo< /p>
< pre> foo try foo word foofoo < /pre>
< /html>
```

shoud be

```
< html>
< p> blah blah blah foo try foo< /p>
< pre> bar try bar word barbar < /pre>
< /html>
```

so , that's means all foo between the tags pre should be replaced by .

i tried to use this regex pattern but its not working.

```
do {
$string = preg_replace('/< pre>([^)]*)foo([^)]*< /pre>)/U', '\1boo\2', $string, -1,$count);
}while($count != 0);
echo $string;
```

im sorry for my english 
Thank you,

Comment: I wish Stack Overflow had a filter that banned questions containing "HTML" and "regex" in the same sentence.

Comment: @BoltClock Or at least a warning poping up when asking a question. Seriously.

Comment: "I want a code" is not how this site works. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BoltClock, would you use a Regex for that kind of filters?

Comment: i have a code , i tried but it not working >

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: Somewhat ironically, yes.

Comment: There are multiple answers in the "Related" links. Your issues: `$count` is not a return parameter, it will not change. `[^)]` should be `[^<>]`. And lastly matching the delimiters with `preg_replace_callback` and replacing the `foo` content separately would be simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = '< html>
< p> blah blah blah foo try foo< /p>
< pre> foo try foo word foofoo < /pre>
< /html>';
$string = preg_replace('/foo(?=(?:.(?!< pre>))*< \/pre>)/Um', 'boo', $string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use DOMDocument to extract the text content of your HTML tags, do a simple str_replace on the text and update the DOM.

Comment: sorry, i want to use only regex pattern to replace all, thanks for your answer .

Comment: @Programmer why? That's like insisting to use a sharpened spoon instead of a scalpell for surgery. Might work in some cases, but it's still the wrong tool for the job. See [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Gordon I think a better analogy would be using a scalpell to cut your bread instead of a bread knife.  Yeah, sure, you can do it, but to do it properly it will take forever!  And you will end up ripping a bunch of the bread (image thats your hair) wondering why its not working right.  Or you could just use DOM and str_replace and problem solved, concise and understandable!

Answer (score 1):

First, go get [Simple HTML Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find the first pre (you can change this or find an array based on documentation on website to suit your needs, but I will make it just for the first pre for now
$html->find('pre', 0)->plaintext = str_replace('foo', 'bar', $html->find('pre', 0)->plaintext);

//Echo HTML
echo $html;
```

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).