# Selecting numbers inside HTML element in PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
<root>
<td align="left"><a title="Testing" href="www.test.com/product/">$129.00</a></td><td valign="bottom">Testing</td></root>
```

How do I go about selecting the `129.00` in the above example? I don't want the `$`.

Currently I have `preg_match('/\$.{6}/')` to select this. This is generally ok, but whenever it becomes a 4 digit string, it fails. Eg. `$50.00`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many will tell you, don't use regex to parse html/xml structures. But if you really want or have to use regex, try this pattern:

`\$([0-9\.]+)`

for alternatives look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Yeah, I know I should use DOM/XPath, but its a really simple document with a few lines of code... really cant be stuffed using extra stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Then I hope the pattern will work for you. But be aware, that it will not match if you have some characters others than `0-9` and `.`. Maybe adding chars for a thousands separator will be needed. (See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)

Comment: It does.. `preg_match('/\$([0-9\.]+)/', $yourString, $matches);` and do `$matches[1]` returns `129` or..how are you using it with other rows?

Comment: @tradybix ohh, my bad. It does work too, I accidentally removed one of the quotes ('). Thanks. However it does not remove the `$`.

Comment: `preg_match` is not the correct function if you want to remove something, look at `preg_replace` for this. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex, got it from here: [Link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0360__Regular-Expression/Matchingmoneydd2.htm)

```
 \$\d+\.\d{2}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...
http://pastebin.com/WqEUKFNn and SQL result (`id 29`): http://img.acianet.co.uk/i/sqlfail.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[replace all "foo" between two HTML tags using REGEX (PHP code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000508/replace-all-foo-between-two-html-tags-using-regex-php-code/6000613#6000613)

```
<?php
$string ='<root>
<td align="left"><a title="Digitan Technology: Click to see item" href="www.digitan.com.au/home.php?cat=2655" target="retailer">$115.20</a></td><td valign="bottom">AMD PHENOM X4 Quad Core 9650 CPU, 2.3GHz (95W), 4MB Cache, Sockets AM2+/AM2</td></root>';
preg_match('/\$([0-9\.]+)(?=(?:.(?!<a))*<\/a>)/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```